# How to use 2 tables data in one query and make a new column based on the 2 tables data's with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table contains **People** details, one for **Currency** details, one for Peoples **Debt**s, and one for **Paid Debts**. 
I want to make a query for showing **Remaining Debts**, like if someone debted *100$* and *100,000IQD* then debted another *250$*, after a while he paid back *150$* and *40,000IQD*, I want the query to show that persons remaining debts in 2 rows, one say *200$* and the other say *60,000IQD*, so the **Remaining Debts** money amount is `sum of debt_amount - sum of paid_amount` for a currency and also for the other.

I can do the summerize for both currencies for each person so it shows the 2 debts of (*100$* and *250$*) as one *350$*, but what causes the problem is that I don't know how to achieve that calculation of getting the remaining amount based on debts and paid ones with MySQL.

Getting all **debts** query:

```sql
SELECT 
    people.id, people.name, SUM(debt_people.amount) AS debt, debt_people.cur_id AS currency_id
FROM
    debt_people 
        INNER JOIN
    people  ON people.id = debt_people.people_id
GROUP BY debt_people.people_id , debt_people.cur_id;
```

[image: the result of depts query]

Getting all **paid depts** query:

```sql
SELECT 
    people.id,
    people.name,
    SUM(payment_people.amount) AS Payment,
    payment_people.cur_id AS currency_id
FROM
    payment_people
        INNER JOIN
    people  ON people.id = payment_people.people_id
GROUP BY payment_people.people_id , payment_people.cur_id;
```

[image: the result of paid debts query]

What I want to achieve is explained in the image below:
[image: expected result]
this shows 2 tables that contain **Debt** and **Paid Debts**, I want to have a query that takes out the amount of paid money for a person based on the currency id from the debts he did before also based on the currency id

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i updated the question, i hope it explains the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want to use `union all` before joining:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, dp.cur_id,
       SUM(dp.debt) AS debt, SUM(dp.payment) as payment,
       SUM(dp.debt) - SUM(dp.payment) as remaining
FROM people p JOIN
     ((SELECT d.people_id, d.amount as debt, 0 as payment, d.cur_id
       FROM dept_people d
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT p.people_id, 0, p.amount as payment, p.cur_id
       FROM payment_people d
      )
     ) dp
     ON p.id = dp.people_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, dp.cur_id;
```

Comment: I changed the code to this because you misspelled **dp** and **pd** a few times, but i still thank you a lot

Comment: here is the new code if you want to update your answer :   ```SELECT p.id, p.name, dp.cur_id,
       SUM(dp.debt) AS debt, SUM(dp.payment) as payment,
       SUM(dp.debt) - SUM(dp.payment) as remaining
FROM people p JOIN
     ((SELECT d.people_id, d.amount as debt, 0 as payment, d.cur_id
       FROM debt_people d
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT d.people_id, 0, d.amount as payment, d.cur_id
       FROM payment_people d
      )
     ) dp
     ON p.id = dp.people_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, dp.cur_id;```

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-aggregate the `debt` and `payment` tables *(to one row per person-currency combination)* and ***then*** join the results...

```
SELECT 
  people.id,
  people.name,
  debt.currency_id,
  debt.amount                                 AS debts,
  payment.amount                              AS payments,
  debt.amount - COALESCE(payment.amount, 0)   AS remaining
FROM
  people
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, cur_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM debt_people
  GROUP BY people_id, cur_id
)
  AS debt
    ON debt.people_id = people.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, cur_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM payment_people
  GROUP BY people_id, cur_id
)
  AS payment
    ON  payment.people_id = debt.people_id
    AND payment.cur_id    = debt.cur_id
```

***NOTE:*** This assumes a payment can always be associated to a debt (same person, same currency)

Comment: thank you, I used @GordonLinoff answer and it works, but thank you :)